# Line break issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

if I use a paragraph element the line doesn't break, but if I use a textarea element the line breaks. why is this?

html:

```
<div id="requirement_7">
    <h3> Requirement #7</h3>
    <p>Press "Show Array" button to see an array created with JSON.<br>
    It will show A state, the capital and quailty rating.</p>
    <button type="button" id="array_button" onclick="JSONArray()">Show Array</button>
    <p id="array_text"></p>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function JSONArray(){
    var text = '{"stateCapital":['+
        '{"stateName":"Texas", "stateCapital":"Austin", "qualityRating":"10"},'+
        '{"stateName":"Virginia", "stateCapital":"Richmond", "qualityRating":"7"},'+
        '{"stateName":"California", "stateCapital":"Sacremento", "qualityRating":"7"},'+
        '{"stateName":"Coloroado", "stateCapital":"Denver", "qualityRating":"10"} ]}';

    var obj = JSON.parse(text);

    document.getElementById("array_text").innerHTML =
    obj.stateCapital[0].stateName + " " + obj.stateCapital[0].stateCapital + " "
    + obj.stateCapital[0].qualityRating + "\n" +

    obj.stateCapital[1].stateName + " " + obj.stateCapital[1].stateCapital + " "
    + obj.stateCapital[1].qualityRating + "\n" +

    obj.stateCapital[2].stateName + " " + obj.stateCapital[2].stateCapital + " "
    + obj.stateCapital[2].qualityRating + "\n" +

    obj.stateCapital[3].stateName + " " + obj.stateCapital[3].stateCapital + " "
    + obj.stateCapital[3].qualityRating;
}
```

I have "\n" in my script to create the line break. I'm confused why it works in one element and not the other?

Comment: In HTML, `\n` doesn't mean "newline". You probably wanted `<br>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to replace `"\n"` with `"<br>"` since you are using `.innerhtml` it recognizes it as HTML and not JavaScript.

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/ojjeKZ?editors=101

Answer (score 0):

You must use <br> to make a line break in paragraph.

If you do not want to change from '\n' to <br> you can use <pre> tag instead of <p> tag.

refer doc:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp